# getOriginal() is not working in laravel 8

Tags: laravel

Below is my Eloquent model

```php
namespace App\Models;
    
use App\Models\BaseModel as Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
    
class Banner extends Model {
    protected $table = 'banners';
    protected $fillable = ['image', 'isactive', 'type'];
    
    protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'deleted_at', 'updated_at'];
    
    public function getImageAttribute($value) {
        if ($value)
            return Storage::url($value);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am using Eloquant statement:

```php
App\Models\Banner::find(2)->getOriginal('image');
```

It is giving accesor value of image attribute instead of original value

Answer (score 18):

Laravel 7.x change **getRawOriginal()** instead of **getOriginal()**...

> The $model->getOriginal() method will now respect any casts and
> mutators defined on the model. Previously, this method returned the
> uncast, raw attributes. If you would like to continue retrieving the
> raw, uncast values, you may use the getRawOriginal method instead.

See: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#factory-types

Comment: Am using laravel 5.7 it says `Method getRawOriginal does not exist`

Comment: @DaniyalNasir The method `getRawOriginal()` can only be used from Laravel 7.x onwards.

Answer (score 8):

You probably want `getRawOriginal` to not have the accessor used.

```
$banner = Banner::findOrFail(2);
$image = $banner->getRawOriginal('image');
// or from the attributes
$image = $banner->getAttributes()['image'] ?? null;
```

Comment: Thanks it is useful. Just curiously want to know that in my old projects on laravel 5.8, 6 getOriginal() was working fine. But in laravel 8 it is not. Is this a change in latest version?

Comment: @pks11 It was changed with Laravel 7, here is a [link](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#factory-types) to the upgrade guide that mentions the change.

Comment: In Laravel 9 I get the following error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder::getRawOriginal()`